# Centos: настройка NGINX + PHP-FPM

Tags: веб-сервер, nginx, php, centos

Добрый вечер. Настраиваю по данному тутору - http://xaxatyxa.ru/_centos/ustanovka-web-server-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-centos.html

1. Захожу по адресу xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, в итоге я автоматически скачиваю файл "загруженное".
2. Создаю файл phpinfo.php, и вместо того, что бы увидеть его на сайте, он так же скачивается ко мне на ПК.

Что делать? Как починить? Никогда с таким не сталкивался. Спасибо.

P.S ОС - Centos 6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP CGI установлен?

Comment: Package php-cli-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 already installed and latest versionИ ещё ошибка:[root@GS ~]# /etc/init.d/php-fpm restartОстанавливается php-fpm:                                   [  OK  ]Запускается php-fpm: [02-Dec-2013 11:21:13] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/module.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @Nicolayka, поставил к себе на сервер нгинкс. Проблема решается следующим образом. (В конфиг)location ~ \.php$ {        try_files $uri =404;        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;        fastcgi_index index.php;        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;}

Comment: Спасибо. У меня другая проблема теперь. Не могу зайти в папку с phpmyadmin. Тупо белый лист и ни единой ошибки --> http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/8864/php-102-recv-failed-104-connection-reset-by-peer-while-reading-response-header-from-upstream